# Store date to firebase and query items in the last 24 hours

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

What's the best way to store dates into Firebase and be able to use query's with it?

I hear that the best way to do it is to store it as time interval. if so, how would I query data stored in the last 24 hours?

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Not really, still looking for a way to do it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you please have a look at my answer to see whether this is the right approach? should I use FIRServerValue.timestamp() when storing the data and retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Can someone confirm whether this is the right approach or not?

Assuming that the data is as follows:

```
"Items" {
 "-KWCwD8uqWyP9LrSkG3j" {
  "name": "Brush"
  "addedBy": "1478774386.282859"
 }
}
```

The swift code of getting time from the last 24 hours should look like this:

```
let timeNow = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
let time24hoursBeforeNow = timeNow - 24 * 60 * 60
```

The query should look something like this:

```
ref.child("Items").queryOrdered(byChild: "addedBy").queryStarting(atValue: timeNow).queryEnding(atValue: time24hoursBeforeNow)
```